# Suppress output of expression register?

Tags: vimrc

Is it possible to suppress the output of a register? For example, I am using `getchar()` to 'consume' a character, but I don't need it to return anything. I suppose I could add in a hackish ternary operator to do this, such as:

```
=getchar()?'':''
```

But I was wondering if there was a cleaner or better way to do this?

Comment: "cleaner" is subjective, but `getchar()[-1]` is shorter.

Comment: @user938271 thanks. Do you want to post an answer and show how that would work? Does the `-1` work differently than for example it does in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"cleaner" is subjective, but `getchar()[-1]` is shorter.

From [`:h expr-[]`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#subscript):

> A negative index always results in an empty string (reason: backward
> compatibility).

Comment: interesting...thanks for the explanation.